# Looking for method equivalent to find previous index of character in string in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an string with some special characters.

The thing is, I want to search those special characters from the end of the string.

Is there any method available to search the index of character in backward direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:` and use `NSBackwardsSearch` for the options argument.

Comment: Hi rdelmar, i'm new to ios development. Could you give me an example to do this. Thank you.